# Rails wicked_pdf file name in PDF reader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

In ma Rails app I have a route (download.pdf) that returns a PDF

```
format.pdf do
  render pdf: "#{@sale.firstname}#{@sale.lastname}", dpi: 400
end
```

The PDF is opened in Chrome as download.pdf but when saving the file it gets saved with the correct file name.

But when opening directly with the PDF reader (instead of Chrome) the file gets downloaded as download.pdf

Any ideas how to solve this without changing the route?

Image: when opening with Chrome it works but when opening with the PDF reader the file name is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Browser uses `Content-Disposition` header to looking for the correct filename for the file. As you say the browser saving the file with the correct file name, it setting up correctly. But PDF reader doesn't check headers because it's not a browser.
You may try to check `response.headers['Content-Disposition']` but looks like you need to change url.